# If i pass serialized json data, where does that appear in the http request?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am attempting to do this: Insert a http validation token into serialized JSON data. I already have working the ability to pass it normally in JSON and also to pass it in a header using a custom authorization extension. What I would like to do is, in the validator, if the request isn't in the header data or in the form data, deserialize the passed data and look in there. I can't actually find the data in the request though. When I read the passed data (84 bytes), i just ended up with a bunch of numbers.

Here's the validator for antiforgery:

```cs
    namespace DispatchCrude.Extensions
    {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class,
                AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
            var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
            //try header first
            var token = httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];
            //try normal method
            if (token == null)
            {
                for(int cl = 0; cl < httpContext.Request.Form.Keys.Count; cl++)
                {
                    if (httpContext.Request.Form.Keys[cl] == "__RequestVerificationToken")
                    {
                        token = httpContext.Request.Form[httpContext.Request.Form.Keys[cl]];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (token == null) 
            {
                //this section isn't finding the passed data
                //get here if form stringified    
                System.IO.Stream str; String strmContents;
                Int32 counter, strLen, strRead;
                // Create a Stream object.
                str = httpContext.Request.InputStream;
                // Find number of bytes in stream.
                strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
                // Create a byte array.
                byte[] strArr = new byte[strLen];
                // Read stream into byte array.
                strRead = str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);

                // Convert byte array to a text string.
                strmContents = "";
                for (counter = 0; counter < strLen; counter++)
                {
                    strmContents = strmContents + strArr[counter].ToString();
                }
                
                token = strmContents; //just so i can debug the returned token
            }
            //if both fail, attempt to check stringified data for matching token.
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, token);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's some example code we are serializing the form data:

```js
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            headers: appendVerificationToken(),
            url: "/OrderSettlement/SessionApplyRatesCancel",
            data: JSON.stringify({ key: data.key }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function () {
                /* decided to NOT close the window (just cancel and show the [CANCELLED] description)
                // on success, close the owning popup
                runFuncByNameSingleParameter(_owningPopup.Close);
                */
            }
        });
```

As I said, passing it in the header works, but I would like to be able to add it to the data instead and I can't find it in the request to parse it.

Comment: Due to the way you've submitted the request, the JSON makes up the entire body of the request. It's not form-encoded data. You can get that body a number of ways. One way (though not necessarily the best) is `string requestBody = await httpRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`.

Comment: i'll try reading it that way and see if i get a good result thanks.

Comment: while i was unable to read it like you posted (it's an annotation so i don't think i can make it async) and it's built into filtercontext, Your information on it becoming the entire request was good enough to send me on the right solution.  This works:  using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.InputStream))
                {
                    json = reader.ReadToEnd(); }

Comment: if you post some kind of answer, i'll accept it.  In the meantime i'm leaving a "placeholder" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Ouroborus, I was able to come up with a solution.
This works:

```
           string json;
            var position = httpContext.Request.InputStream.Position;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 8192, true))
            { 
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //you MUST reset the input stream to start or you will break post.
                httpContext.Request.InputStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                try
                {
                    var jsonObj = Json.Decode(json); //attempt to parse into json object.  
                    token = jsonObj["__RequestVerificationToken"];
                }
                catch
                {
                    //eat the parse errors.  That simply means it's not json.
                }
            }
```

I hope it helps someone else.  Note that you must reset the stream back to zero, exactly how I'm doing it, or the controller function won't receive any passed data.